# java: run process by crontab

Tags: java

My search system has two main parts: index and search. I want to make the index as a java process which can be called by crontab. But I have no idea how to implement this. Could someone tell my how to do it?

Comment: I know how to create a crontab job by using java -jar command from google, but I have no idea how to do the same job by using java process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use Quartz to schedule tasks inside JVM: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger
2. You can set up a crontab script which simply launches some Java application (e.g. java -jar MyTask.jar) which does the job.

Comment: thank you. I know how run a job by crontab. but the question is that I don't know the strategy that how to crontab a java process. like when the server is running, it will create a index process, but how crontab can run this process?

Comment: Using cron-tab you can launch a new process, which exits when it finishes. Or you can use Quartz to schedule a job inside JVM (i.e. it doesn't exit when a scheduled job is finished). Basically I see two options for this. I would choose Quartz as it keeps everything in one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to create a crontab entry, refer to the Unix / Linux manual entries for `crontab`:

```
$ man 1 crontab
$ man 5 crontab
```

If you don't have the manual entries installed on your machine, Google can find them for you.